LaTeX Dvips PS to PDF
How to generate PDF with Nimbus Roman font using the method of LaTeX->DVIPS->ps2pdf or distiller with mathtime package. All the Nimbus italics in math font are getting converted to Times in PDF, how stop changing Nimbus to Times?
I don't want to use mathptmx/newtxmath/txfonts only from the mathtime package.
In PDFLaTeX this works fine but I want to have it from LaTeX->DVIPS->ps2pdf or distiller.

Provide full but minimal example so we know exactly what you're doing

I have solved the above problem by using argument for dvips -D600 -Ppdf -R0 -tunknown -u xxx/pdftex/config/pdftex.map xxx\Sample.dvi it resulted in Nimbus font in PDF, is this approach correct?

I haven't used the dvips route in years so no idea. But it is better to show us which packages you are using hence why I ask for a minimal example
